# how to change columns suggestion order in oracle sql developer 4.1? Defaultly suggestion popup is in alphabetical order

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to change columns suggestion order in oracle sql developer 4.1? Defaultly suggestion popup is in alphabetical order, how to change it to as per table column order?

My table structure is:

```
TABLE NAME: CMS_EMP
---------------------
ID    NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
NAME  VARCHAR2(35),
GRADE VARCHAR2(5),
SAL   NUMBER(18,2)
```

In Oracle sql developer column suggestion popup is giving me list as

```
GRADE
ID
NAME
SAL
```

But I want column suggestion as per table column order like

```
ID
NAME
GRADE
SAL
```

How to do this? What is the settings to be changed in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER?

Answer (score 0):

There's no preference/toggle/setting to change this behavior.

The why - while you may know this table intimately, because you created it, or you have memorized your data model - those coming after you might find it hard to find the column or columns in the list.

This becomes much more apparent for tables with more than 4 columns.

Now, is there any relief the tool can offer you?

Yes, if you know what you want, type the first letter of the column you want - then the insight list will only pull columns starting with that letter.

If you want the entire column list, expcliitely called out (not using *), and you want to preserve the order as shown in the table, you could:

[image]

Hover over the '*' - we'll give you the column list, click the list to insert it into the query and replace the '*'

[image]